# Bootstrap 3 Options Menu Disappears

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, options-menu

I have a table of 4 columns using the Bootstrap 3 grid system. Instead of using the `col-xs-*`, which works great on mobile, I used the `col-md-*`. The reason was simple -- on mobile, I didn't want the icons to shrink down very small and wanted them larger and visible on mobile. When I switched from `col-xs-*` to `col-md-*` for these columns, the mobile would automatically stack the icons in the grid and keep them large -- which is exactly what I want.

Okay, all is well except that somehow **this makes the document width get messed up**, and the Options Menu (the three-bar popdown menu for mobiles/tablets) disappears **because it's aligned to the document width, not the viewport width**.

Does anyone know a good CSS fix for that common problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of my problem. It wasn't because of the responsive columns. It was because inside my responsive columns, I was doing absolute positioning in a relative container so that my `P` tag would align to the bottom of a box, but then my text wasn't centered, so I applied this:

```
.box P
{
position:absolute;
bottom:5px;
left:-50%;
right:-50%;
}
```

When I did that, it caused the options menu to jump off screen. The fix was that I switched the left and right like so:

```
.box P
{
position: absolute;
bottom: 5px;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

This centered that P tag text inside the responsive columns, but yet still allowed me to use absolute positioning inside a box of the grid that was set to `position:relative`. This caused the document width to act normal again and thus the Options Menu reappeared.